# Can't switch SetMkeyState for G13 via mouse G600

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to assighn
SetMkeyState M1 "lhc" to G18
SetMkeyState M2 "lhc" to G19
SetMkeyState M3 "lhc" to G20

Here my code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 18) then
SetMKeyState(2,"lhc");
end
end
```

the problem is, there no reaction of G13 :(

Comment: `G_PRESSED` is generated by G13.  G600 generates `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED`.

Comment: Egor! I apologize for such simple mistakes   , and thank you for your help!